# How to track status of rows successfully processed or failed in SSIS data flow task?

Tags: ssis, audit

I have a very simple Data flow task reading data from a FF and inserting the data in a table. At the same time I would like to write in an Audit table, how many rows have been inserted, the created date...

How can I do that easily?

Comment: I would like to populate an audit table with the number of rows inserted into the target table . Something similar to the @@rowcount??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are interested only in the number of rows being successfully processed or number of rows that encountered errors, then you can make use of in-built `SSIS logging` feature. Please check the below mentioned steps. I hope the example gives you an idea. I have displayed only two columns from the log table but there are other useful fields like starttime, endtime etc., The example was created in **`SSIS 2008 R2`**

1. Click on the `SSIS package`.
2. On the menus, select `SSIS --> Logging...`
3. On the Configure *SSIS Logs:* dialog, select the provider type and click Add. I have chosen SQL Server for this example. Check the Name checkbox and provide the data source under Configuration column. Here SQLServer is the name of the connection manager. `SSIS 2008` or `SSIS 2008 R2` will create a table named **dbo.sysssislog** and stored procedure **dbo.sp_ssis_addlogentry** in the database that you selected. Refer screenshot **#1** below. The table name in `SSIS 2005` is **dbo.sysdtslog90** and the stored procedure is named as **dbo.sp_dts_addlogentry**
4. If you need the rows processed, select the checkbox OnInformation. Here in the example, the package executed successfully so the log records were found under OnInformation. You may need to fine tune this event selection according to your requirements. Refer screenshot **#2** below.
5. Here is a sample package execution within data flow task. Refer screenshot **#3** below.
6. Here is a sample output of the log table dbo.sysssislog. I have only displayed the columns **id** and **message**. There are many other columns in the table. In the query, I am filtering the output only for the package named '**Package1**' and the event '**OnInformation**'. You can notice that records with ids 7, 14 and 15 contain the rows processed. Refer screenshot **#4** below.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1**:

[image: Logging]

**Screenshot #2**:

[image: Events]

**Screenshot #3**:

[image: Execution]

**Screenshot #4**:

[image: Data]

Comment: by the way, I followed your explanation in my package but I cannot find the table 'dbo.sysssislog' in SQL Server. Is it under System Databases?

Comment: strange I don't have it in my System Tables

Comment: Maybe it is because my server is sql server 2000?

Comment: OK never mind! I think this is where issue comes from because your SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '%ssis%' OR name LIKE '%dts%' doesn't return anything..

Comment: Otherwise, is it not possible to use the row count transformation to have something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can multicast the flat file, or use a trigger on the table you're inserted data to. If it's a table that's being audited you'll probably want to know whenever **any** data is inserted.